# How can I export module OpenCV via Pyinstaller if it is not imported in project?

Tags: opencv, pyinstaller

I created a Bot which uses pyautogui function locateOnScreen to detect certain things on my monitor. In this locateOnScreen function i use confidence parameter which is only possible because i installed OpenCV module via pip. To use this confidence parameter you only have to have opencv installed but do NOT have to import it in your project. Now if i want to make a executable via pyinstaller i get an error which says that there is no module OpenCV.

Comment: Post a [mcve] and include software version numbers. End of Review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was two days over it.

*"I found a solution! Turns out the current version of opencv (4.5.4.58) is not compatible with the current version of pyinstaller, I installed the previous version of opencv (4.5.3.56) and it worked!"*

```
pip install opencv-python==4.5.3.56
```

I'm using PyInstaller to transform in exe.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1342433/opencv-pyinstaller-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5

Comment: Thank you very much this solved my problem but i ran into a new one. Now if i use pyinstaller to create a .exe i get another error (ModuleNotFoundError) if i want to open this exe on another PC. It looks like Pyinstaller took a path from my PC which is included in the error message when i open the executable on another PC. The module which cant  be found is _socket but this problem might occurr with more modules if pyinstaller takes the path on my pc.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:[ ]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "multiprocessing__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "multiprocessing\context.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 16, in <module>

Comment: File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "socket.py", line 51, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_socket'